# Does .toPromise() make Angular Http requests more performant?

Tags: angular, performance, rxjs, angular-http

Does [Angular http](https://angular.io/api/common/http)'s .toPromise() change how the xml request is made, or does it just convert the underlying observable-like functionality/responses into a promise-like functionality?

I've heard that promises were built with http calls in mind, and are more performant than observables. I'm hoping to find some sort of proof for this claim one way or another.

Comment: No, it just uses a slightly different mechanism. Don't do this "to make it faster" doe this because you want a promise based system instead of a functional programming based system (i.e. rxjs). Also be **very** wary of "makes it faster", faster when? What does faster mean, etc. The only way to be sure about this, is to test it. `I'm hoping to find some sort of proof for this claim one way or another.` this doesn't exist

Comment: FYI an observable is a rxjs object. Angular just uses rxjs under the hood. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable

Comment: It's not Angular Http's toPromise  - it's RxJS' toPromise. toPromise just subscribes to the Observable and returns a Promise that resolves the last emitted value. So an additional Promise is created. Why should this be faster than subscribing yourself?

Answer (score 0):

`.toPromise` no more then converting an `Observable` sequence to a ES2015 compliant promise.